# How to get mouses scrollX value from a point of event's call in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know mouse scrollX value not by left window's border, but by element that has triggered an event. Thank you, i rely on you guys!

Comment: The scrollbar X (horizontal) position the moment an event is triggered?

Comment: Yes and the starting point must be the same that triggered an event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [scrollLeft()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/) to get the container current scroll position.

Use `$(elem).position().left` to get the element position depending on the current scroll position of the container.

Here's a JsFiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cb3jaLgr/)

Comment: And what about to get mouse X scroll position not considering previous mouse scroll?

Comment: You just want everything on a plate don't you? Put some effort into your own work. When the answer has been written for you, you shift the goal posts... this is ridiculous way to act on SO

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want, but look at the JsFiddle, `ScrollingLength` is the scroll X position value of the element, regardless of the current scroll. (you can remove "shift")